Visual Studio 2022 rdlc dataset from object
I am trying to add a dataset from a custom class created in my project, in previous versions I have been able to add them directly with the object option, now in Visual Studio 2022, that option does not appear, I can only add from database models
Image from previous visual studio version where you see the Object option
https://i.sstatic.net/BOO2TXjz.png
